# Eclipse doesn't suggest a class that needs to be imported later

Tags: java, eclipse

I don't know if this is a bug or it's just how it's supposed to be، but whenever I try to type a class like the class random, in eclipse it doesn't give me a suggestion for it. Even when I press Ctrl + Space.

PS: However eclipse does tell me to import the class when I hover the mouse over it.

Comment: It works for others, so it is very unlikely a bug. Code completion offers different suggestions at different locations. Show a code example and tell where you hit Ctrl+Space and tell which proposals you expect. Tell also, the Java and Eclipse versions used and whether it's a Java file inside a source folder or not. When you expect something from a module (Java 9 or higher), you have also tell whether you have a `module-info.java` file with the corresponding `requires` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing to try is cleaning your projects via top menus: `Project` > `Clean`

note: pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> multiple times will cycle through different content assist proposals.  Also <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> will bring up the quick fixes dialog for errors on your current cursor's line.

I had a similar issue recently, go to:

`Window > Preferences` then `Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced`

In there I unchecked all the boxes and clicked `Apply` at the bottom.  Then turned on the same options I had just disabled and clicked `Apply` again and that fixed it.

[image]